# Meteor's onCreateUser not firing when running createUser from server

Tags: meteor, user-accounts

I've added a form on the front page of my meteor app taking an email and name of users. It sends an enrollment email with a link for them to create a password. There are a lot of background profile settings that need to be added when the account is created and it functions from the {{loginButtons}} account creation. For some reason, onCreateUser isn't functioning when called from createUser. Where have I gone wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Registration form**:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horiztonal" id="signup">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input name="name" id="name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Get Started!" class="btn btn-success"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Page Event**:

```
 Template.landing.events({
'submit form#signup' : function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var user = {
        name: $(e.target).find('[name=name]').val(),
        email: $(e.target).find('[name=email]').val()
    }

    Meteor.call('signup', user, function(error, id) {
        if (error) {
                // display the error to the user
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                Router.go('awesome');
            }
        });

}
```

});

**Signup Method (in server)**:

```
Meteor.methods({
signup: function(user) {

// ensure the user is logged in
if (!user)
  throw new Meteor.Error(401, "Can't make a user without a user object");

// ensure the user has a name
if (!user.name)
  throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a name');

// ensure there is an email
if (!user.email)
  throw new Meteor.Error(424, 'Please fill in an email address');  

var userId = Accounts.createUser(user);
if(userId) {
Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId);
return userId;
}
}
 });
```

**onCreateUser (in server)**:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    if (options.profile) {
        user.profile                        =   options.profile;                //Copy initial profile settings
        //Set roles
        user.roles                          =   ["User"];


        //Account settings
        user.profile.active                 =   false;                          //Account is not active on creation
        user.profile.trial                  =   true;                           //Accounts have 1 month trial
        user.profile.expiration             =   moment().add('M', 1);           //No expiration date on unactivated accounts

        user.profile.bill                   =   null;                           //Bill monthly, yearly
        user.profile.ppId                   =   null;                           //Paypal Id for associated credit card

        user.profile.resources              =   0;                              //Number of resources an account has created
        user.profile.resourceLimit          =   2;                              //Limit for the number of resources an account can have

        //User settings
        user.profile.name                   =   null;                           //Name is blank when created
        user.profile.phone                  =   null;                           //Phone is blank when created
        user.profile.createdOn              =   moment().toISOString();         //Createdon tracks when account created
    }

    return user;
});
```

Comment: You didn't post your `onCreateUser` function. Are you getting any errors in the node console?

Comment: @Cuberto Posted now, sorry I forgot. Not getting any node console errors or errors in browser console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't providing a `profile` field when you call `Accounts.createUser(options)`. So when your `onCreateUser()` function tests for:

```js
if (options.profile) {
  // ...
}
```

`options.profile` doesn't exist and none of your custom fields are added. Try changing your code to something like this:

```js
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  // Use provided profile in options, or create an empty profile object
  user.profile = options.profile || {};
  user.roles = ["User"];

  // Add additional fields

  return user;
});
```

Also note that the `profile` is intended for user-modifiable fields by convention and is published to the user by default. So most of those fields you're adding to the `profile` should probably be added to the user object directly or to a separate user field of your choice. From the Meteor docs:

> `profile`: an Object which (by default) the user can create and update with any data.
>   ...
>   By default, the current user's `username`, `emails` and `profile` are published to the client.